# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta a varias tablas desde webapi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Estoy tratando de realizar la siguiente consulta por medio de una API en .net:

```
select Nota.Corte, Nota.Nota, Materia.Descripcion as Materia
from [dbo].[NotaParcial] Nota
inner join
[dbo].[Matricula] Matricula
on Nota.MatriculaId=Matricula.MatriculaId
inner join Persona
on Matricula.PersonaId= Persona.PersonaId
inner join [dbo].[Materia] Materia
on Materia.MateriaId = Matricula.MateriaId
and Matricula.Semestre=''
and Matricula.ProgramaId=(select Descripcion from [dbo].[Programa] where Descripcion='')
and Persona.Email=''
```

No se cómo realizarla, desde la api o mediante algún método, necesito traer esa información, y donde se encuentran los '' pasar los parámetros que traigo desde un formulario ¿Qué puedo hacer?.

Comment: Lo que entiendo yo de tu pregunta, es que tienes una API y quieres que te retorne los mismo datos que tienes en la consulta. Pero no entiendo si te refieres a modificar la API o hacer que pasándole parámetros a la API esta retorne la misma información. De cualquier manera, falta muchísima información a tu pregunta para poder responderla.

Comment: @Yussef tenemos una API en .net, con sus modelos, controladores y demas, lo que necesitamos es que en el controlador de una de las tablas, plasmar esta misma consulta en un metodo GET, el problema es que no sabemos como.

Comment: Entonces, te refieres a pasar esa consulta SQL a Linq ???

Comment: @Yussef siii, me serviria tambien asi, pero no se como

Comment: Para esos debes tener las clases (modelo) que intervienen en esa consulta (notaparcial, matricula, persona, programa y materia) y publicarlas aquí (editando tu pregunta original)